# Why does every "fibonacci like" series converge to $\phi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

It's is well known that the ratio of side-by-side fibonacci numbers converge to $\phi$. But it seems by my calculations, that if one starts with any pair of numbers one will also get a ratio that converges to $\phi$. Say for example if one starts with $3$ and $4$ we get:

```
4   1,333333333
7   1,75
11  1,571428571
18  1,636363636
29  1,611111111
47  1,620689655
76  1,617021277
123 1,618421053
199 1,617886179
322 1,618090452
521 1,618012422
843 1,618042226
```

where the series is on the left and the ratio is side-by-side numbers are on the right.

I'm quite curious to know why this happens. Anyone?

Comment: Oh... that list didn't print out well... here it comes again:

Comment: 3 

4 1,333333333

7 1,75

11 1,571428571

18 1,636363636

29 1,611111111

47 1,620689655

76 1,617021277

123 1,618421053

199 1,617886179

322 1,618090452

521 1,618012422

843 1,618042226

1364 1,618030842

2207 1,618035191

Comment: It is not *completely* true. There is the uninteresting case where the starting numbers are $0,0$. And the almost equally uninteresting case where the starting numbers are $a\ne 0$ and $a\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: The general solution to $x_{n} = x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$ is $x_n = a\varphi^n + b\varphi'^n$ for constants $a$ and $b$, where $\varphi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ and $\varphi' = (1-\sqrt{5})/2$. As  long as $a \not= 0$ we have $x_{n+1}/x_n = (\varphi + (b\varphi'/a)(\varphi'/\varphi)^n)/(1 + (b/a)(\varphi'/\varphi)^n)$, and since $\varphi = 1.618... > 1$ and $|\varphi'| < 1$ we have $|\varphi'/\varphi| < 1$, so $x_n \rightarrow \varphi$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This calculation is *false* if $a = 0$, e.g., if $x_n = \varphi'^n$ then $x_{n+1}/x_n = \varphi'$ for all $n$.

Comment: btw, the Fibonacci sequence is unique: the ratios are the convergents of the continued fraction of $\varphi$. So, in one sense, even though the other sequences converge to $\varphi$, the fibonacci ratios are the best approximations.

Comment: That's not working very well... But I hope you understand my question. I'm refering to my list of numbers :)  This is interesting though... I'll have to give this some thought.

Comment: KCd, this is very interesting. I understand how the ratio converges to phi. But could you possibly elaborate a bit on how the solution $x_n=aφ^n+bφ′^n$ is found?

Answer (score 29):

Let's define a Fibonacci-like sequence to be a sequence satisfying:
$$s_n=s_{n-1}+s_{n-2}.$$
Notice that if we take two Fibonacci-like sequences and add them together, we get another Fibonacci-like sequence - that is, if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Fibonacci-like, then so is $a_n+b_n$ - you can check the recurrence yourself. Similarly, if we scale every term of a Fibonacci-like sequence by a constant, it is still Fibonacci-like - that is, if $a_n$ is Fibonacci-like, so is $c\cdot a_n$.

This means that such sequences form a structure called a *vector space* -  that is, if we set up a linear combination on Fibonacci-like sequences (e.g. $\alpha\cdot a_n + \beta \cdot b_n$), the result is still Fibonacci-like. However, what's crucial about this insight is that, since we can easily prove that any Fibonacci-like sequence is determined by its first two terms, then if we take two sequences $F_n$, which is the Fibonacci sequence starting with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$ and a similar sequence $F'_n=F_{n-1}$, which starts $F'_0=1$ then $F'_1=0$ we can show that if, for a Fibonacci-like sequence $s$ we have
$$s_0=s_0\cdot F'_0+s_1\cdot F_0$$
$$s_1=s_0\cdot F'_1+s_1\cdot F_1$$
then, since the right hand side is Fibonacci-like, being a linear combination of Fibonacci-like sequences, and since the right hand sequence agrees for the first two terms, which determine the sequence, we can immediately leap to
$$s_n=s_0\cdot F'_n+s_1\cdot F_n$$
or, replacing $F'$ by its definition
$$s_n=s_0\cdot F_{n-1}+s_1\cdot{F_n}$$
that is to say, that $s_n$ can be written as a linear combination of the Fibonacci sequence and a shift of it. Then, the ratio of successive terms is
$$\frac{s_0\cdot F_{n}+s_1\cdot F_{n+1}}{s_0\cdot F_{n-1}+s_1\cdot F_n}$$
which, if we divide both numerator and denominator by $F_n$ gives
$$\frac{s_0+s_1\cdot \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}}{s_0\cdot \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}+s_1}$$ but since $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ tends to $\varphi$ for large $n$ and $\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$ tends to $\varphi^{-1}$, we can see that the above will tend towards
$$\frac{s_0+\varphi s_1}{\varphi^{-1} s_0 + s_1}$$
which equals $\varphi$, since the denominator multiplied by $\varphi$ is the numerator. So, this establishes that any Fibonacci-like sequence must have the same limiting ratio as the Fibonacci sequence, which is $\varphi$. A note of caution is that if the denominator, $\varphi^{-1} s_0 + s_1$ is zero, (i.e. if $s_1=\frac{-s_0}{\varphi}$) then this doesn't work - indeed, in this case, it must be that $s_n=s_0\cdot (-\varphi)^{-n}$ and the limiting ratio is $\frac{1}{\varphi}$.

A deeper result is to notice that $s_n=\varphi^n$ and $s'_n=(-\varphi)^{-n}$ are both Fibonacci sequences as well, which lead to Binet's formula when you find a linear combination of those two equalling the Fibonacci sequence. Clearly, the exponentially growing $s_n$ term dominators the decaying $s'_n$ term, which is why $\phi$ is the limit of the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers; if you want to derive this, notice that $\varphi$ is the solution to
$$s_n=s_{n-1}+s_{n-2}$$
$$\varphi^n = \varphi^{n-1} + \varphi^{n-2}$$
Or, dividing by $\varphi^{n-2}$ gives
$$\varphi^2=\varphi+1$$
which is indeed a property of the golden ratio, and exactly the equation it comes from.

Comment: What a wonderful answer.

Comment: what a terrible answer! $\color{white}{(+1)\ =)}$

Comment: Awesome answer...

Answer (score 7):

The sequences that satisfy the linear recurrence

$$G_{n+2} = G_{n+1} + G_n$$

take the general form

$$ A \alpha^n + B \beta^n$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of

$$x^2 = x + 1 $$

If $A \ne 0$ (and $\alpha$ is the larger root), the ratio of two consecutive such terms $G_{n+1}/G_n$, converges to the larger root, which in this case is the golden ratio: $\varphi$.

$$ G_{n+1}/G_n = \frac{A \alpha^{n+1} + B \beta^{n+1}}{A \alpha^n + B \beta^n}$$

Take the larger root out ($\alpha$)

$$ = \alpha\left(\frac{A + B (\beta/\alpha)^{n+1}}{A  + B (\beta/\alpha)^n}\right) \to \alpha$$

If $A = 0$ and $B \ne 0$, then it converges to $\beta$.

Comment: More elaboration on the general form of a recurrence relation please. Otherwise brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

In case of interest, this phenomenon is not restricted to Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, or that law. Even if we stick with linear degree two recurrences, for example 
$$ \color{magenta}{ x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n}, $$
the ratio of consecutive numbers in the sequence has a well defined limit, in this case the largest root of
$$ \lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 1 = 0,  $$ or
$$  2 + \sqrt 3 \approx 3.73205,   $$
at least as long as we start with, say, $x_1 \geq x_0.$ So, take
$$ 1, 1, 3, 11, 41, 153, 571, 2131, 7953, 29681,  $$ or
$$ 1, 2, 7, 26, 97, 362, 1351, 5042, 18817,    $$
For the first sequence, there are constants $A,B,$  with $A > 0,$ such that 
$$ x_n = A \, \left(2 + \sqrt 3 \right)^n + B \,  \left(2 - \sqrt 3 \right)^n. $$
For the second sequence, there are (probably different) constants $C,D,$  with $C > 0,$ such that 
$$ x_n = C \, \left(2 + \sqrt 3 \right)^n + D \,  \left(2 - \sqrt 3 \right)^n. $$

For either sequence, a number divided by the previous number in the sequence is approximately $2 + \sqrt 3.$

Answer (score 1):

$S_n=\phi^n$ and $S_n=(-\phi)^n$ are two solutions of the Fibonacci recurrence $S_n+S_{n+1}=S_{n+2}$, because $1+\phi=\phi^2$ and $1-\phi^{-1}=\phi^{-2}$.

By linearity, any combination $S_n=a\phi^n+b(-\phi)^{-n}$ is also a solution. You can adjust $a$ and $b$ to match any two initial values. For instance,

$$S_0=3=a\cdot1+b.1,\\S_1=4=a\cdot\phi-b.\phi^{-1},$$
giving
$$a=\frac{3\phi^{-1}+4}{\phi+\phi^{-1}},\\b=\frac{3\phi-4}{\phi+\phi^{-1}}.$$ 
For growing $n$ the powers of $-\phi$ quickly become neglictible (except if $a=0$), and
$$S_n\approx a\cdot\phi^n,$$a geometric progression of ratio $\phi$.

$$\begin{align}
& S_n & a\phi^n\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
& 3 & 2.61803398875 \\
& 4 & 4.23606797750 \\
& 7 & 6.85410196625 \\
& 11 & 11.0901699437 \\
& 18 & 17.9442719100 \\
& 29 & 29.0344418537 \\
& 47 & 46.9787137637 \\
& 76 & 76.0131556175 \\
& 123 & 122.991869381 \\
& 199 & 199.005024999 \\
& 322 & 321.996894380 \\
& 521 & 521.001919379 \\
& 843 & 842.998813759 \\
& 1364 & 1364.00073314 \\
& 2207 & 2206.99954690 \\
& 3571 & 3571.00028003 \\
& 5778 & 5777.99982693 \\
& 9349 & 9349.00010696 \\
& 15127 & 15126.9999339 \\
& 24476 & 24476.0000409 \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

@frimann bjornsson: 
Your sequence is $3,4,7,\ldots$, with first index $1$, so $u_1=3$, $u_2=4$, $\ldots$.  You can check that
$$u_n = (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1} + (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}$$

This formula allows us find particular terms of the sequence, for instance 
$$u_{96}=186982561199565069121\\
u_{97}=302544139324403592003\\
u_{98} = 489526700523968661124\\
u_{99} = 792070839848372253127$$

Consider $u_{99} = (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{100} + (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{100}$. If we multiply by $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ we get $(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{101} + (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{100}\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which is almost $u_{100} = (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{101} + (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{101}$, with a tiny error of $(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{100}\cdot \sqrt{5}$.  Some high precision calculation gives:

$$u_{99} \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = 792070839848372253127 \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \\ =1281597540372340914251.00000000000000000000282306564641\ldots $$
while $\ \ u_{100} = 1281597540372340914251$

The same thing works in general.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n$ be such a sequence, and suppose the limit exists. Then,

$$ L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_{n-1} + s_{n-2}}{s_{n-1}} = 1 + \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_{n-1}}{s_{n-2}} \right)^{-1} = 1 + L^{-1}$$

We see the limit is nonzero and noninfinite, and thus we can simplify to $L^2 - L - 1 = 0$, meaning that either $L = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ or $L = (1 - \sqrt{5})/2$.

There is actually a counterexample to your hypothesis! Suppose we define

- $s_0 = 1$
- $s_1 = (1 - \sqrt{5})/2$
- $s_n = s_{n-1} + s_{n-2}$

Then you will find that the limit converges to $(1 - \sqrt{5})/2$.